# Is it possible to access remote page iframe DOM via AIR AS3 HTMLLoader?

Tags: actionscript-3, iframe, air, flash-cs6

There is a page:
http://vkontakte.ru/share.php?url=google.com
that has an IFRAME.
I try to access `IFRAME DOM`:

```
   html = new HTMLLoader();
   var urlReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://vkontakte.ru/share.php?url=google.com");
   ...

   trace(html.window.document); // return DOM object. It's ok.
   trace(html.window.document.getElementsByTagName("iframe").contentDocument); // return undefined, and that is the problem
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do it. I tryed different approaches but the thing is : you cannot access IFrame content if your not in the same domain and even if you use `loadString` instead of a simple `load` call and even if `placeLoadStringContentInApplicationSandbox` is set to true.
May be there is a way to cheat the integrated browser and tell him :

> It's Ok, I am in the same domain.

But I don't see how do it in flash.